Nginx doesn't see the files from all the static folders
I have this program structure:
my_app
|- app.py
|- exstensions.py
|- run.py
|- blueprints
   |- admin  
      └── static
          ├── file1.css
          └── file2.js 
      └── templates
          └── base.html
      └── routes.py

   ├── home
       └── static
           ├── file1.css
           └── file2.js
       └── templates
           └── index.html
       └── routes.py

   │── authentication
       └── static
           ├── file3.css
           └── file4.js
       └── templates
           └── register.html
       └── routes.py


The problem is that only the static files from home are visible.
This is what I tried in the config file of nginx:

If I let only this, the static files from home are shown in the browser:

location /static/ {
alias "C:/Old D/Facultate/nginx-1.24.0/html/my_app/blueprints/home/static/";
}



But I want to have visible also the static files from authentication when register.html is opened. I tried to put this in config, but it still takes only the static files from home

location /static/ {
alias "C:/Old D/Facultate/nginx-1.24.0/html/my_app/blueprints/home/static/";
}

location /static-auth/ {
alias "C:/Old D/Facultate/nginx-1.24.0/html/my_app/blueprints/authentication/static/";
}

Question:
What can I do to access the static from all the sub folders?
I'm working on Windows 10
